# Add Parser Options to .eslintrc

Tags: eslint, prettier

I have added an .eslintrc to my angular project with this simple config.

```
{
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser", # this by itself works fine
  "parserOptions": { 
    "project": "./tsconfig.json" # this is throwing an error
  }
}
```

I was reading about extending it with parser options in the official docs but my Prettier Eslint terminal is complaining

```
Error: Unexpected token (5:3)
  3 |   "parserOptions": {
  4 |     "project":
> 5 |   }
    |   ^
```

Answer (score 0):

It should go in the overrides array. I'm not sure why this is the case or how it's not called out in the documentation...

```
{
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.ts"],
      "parserOptions": {
        "project": ["tsconfig.json"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```